# Enable default code highlighting in [rust] tag questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

[I've asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217570/enable-default-code-highlighting-in-rust-tag-questions) for this feature on meta before it had been split into meta-stackoverflow and meta-stackexchange, however for some reason it was ignored. I thought it would be helpful to repeat it again here.

Currently [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) language tag behaves unlike other language tags: it does not appear first in the list of tags as other language tags do and it also does not trigger code highlighting in code blocks.

Code highlighting for Rust, however, does work when it is explicitly enabled via `<!-- language: lang-rust -->`.

Could someone please enable default language highlighting for [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)?

Comment: Yeah, would be nice. Right now I'm putting a `<!-- language-all: lang-rust -->` every time I answer...

Comment: Tags are sorted by usage... no special treatment for language tags.